# How to apply tolower to a string vector?

Tags: c++, vector, character, tolower

Since `tolower` only works for individual characters, how would I use `tolower` for a string vector?  I know I would have to go through each individual character of each item, however I am unsure how to access the individual characters within each item.
eg:-

```
string vector[Apple, Banana].
```

`vector[0]` is Apple but I want the character not the whole string.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a string vector? Do you mean a vector of strings? Did you try `vector[0][0]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std; 

int main() { 
vector<string> fruits;
fruits.push_back("Apple");
fruits.push_back("Banana");
for(int i = 0; i<fruits.size(); i++){
    for(auto& c : fruits[i])
    {
        c = tolower(c);
    }
    cout << fruits[i] << endl;
}
}
```

Basically we loop through the character in the vector and make it tolower.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) can help you here to apply `tolower` to each character in each string inside in your vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    //Your vector of strings
    std::vector<std::string> fruits = { "Apple", "Banana" };

    //Loop through vector
    for (auto &fruit : fruits)
    {
        //Apply tolower to each character of string
        std::transform(fruit.begin(), fruit.end(), fruit.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    }

    for (auto const& fruit : fruits)
        std::cout << fruit << ' ';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qs33f6)

---

As @AlanBirtles suggested you could apply `std::transform` for the outer loop too. Then it becomes like this:

```
std::transform(fruits.begin(), fruits.end(), fruits.begin(),
    [](std::string &fruit)
    {
        std::transform(fruit.begin(), fruit.end(), fruit.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
        return fruit;
    });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WKWfMc)

Comment: Outer loop could use `std::transform` too